# Como fazer consulta (SELECT * FROM table) usando AJAX?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax

Olá estou tentando fazer uma consulta em uma tabela e mostrar os resultados na página cliente sem a necessidade de atualizar a página a cada novo cadastro. Porem não estou conseguindo. Seguem os códigos:

index.php

```
<button id="fetchLojas"  class="btn btn-primary" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#selloja" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
        Consultar/Excluir/Editar lojas
</button>

<div class="collapse" id="selloja">
        <div class="well">
          <h1 class="page-header">Alteração de loja <small>Escolha qual loja você quer altera ou excluir</small></h1>
          <h1 class="page-header"><small>Todas lojas</small></h1>

          <div class="" id="mostraLojas">

          </div>

          <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#selloja" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
            Voltar
          </button>

        </div>
      </div>
```

fetch.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#fetchLojas").on("click", function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: "../php/fetchLojas.php"
    }).done(function(data){
        $(this).empty().append("<li>"+ data +"</li>");
    });
});
});
```

fetchLojas.php

```
<?php

require_once "dbconf.php";
$dbconf = new db_connection;

$dbconf->connect_db(); //estabelecendo conexão com o banco de dados
$conn = $dbconf->conn;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM lojas ORDER BY id_lojas DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    echo '
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="panel-title"><b>Loja '. $row["nome"].'</b>
        &nbsp&nbsp<a href="http://digyx.com.br/bkp/lojas/editar-lojas.php?loja='.$row['id_lojas'].'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        <span class="sr-only">Editar Loja</span>
        &nbsp&nbsp<a href="http://digyx.com.br/bkp/lojas/exclui-lojas.php?loja='.$row['id_lojas'].'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Exluir"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        <span class="sr-only">Excluir Loja</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Nome Banco: </b>'. $row["nomebanco"].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Nome arquivo .sql: </b>'. $row["nomearquivo_sql"].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Nome arquivo .tar.gz: </b>'. $row["nomearquivo_targz"].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Usuário do banco de dados: </b>'. $row["bduser"].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Diretorio da loja: </b>'. $row["pasta_loja"].'</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    ';

}
} else {
echo "Nenhuma loja cadastrada!";
}

$dbconf->close_db(); //fechando conexão com banco de dados
```

O que quero é quando clicar no botão Consultar Lojas (id="fetchLojas"), a consulta aconteça e mostre os dados na div (id="mostraLojas"), porem quando clico no botão não mostra nada.

Se alguem puder me ajudar a ver o que está errado, agradeço!!!

Comment: Dica, retorne a estrutura em um json ou xml, e popule o html usando js

Comment: não sei como se faz isso =(

Comment: Algo mais ou menos assim: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3351882/convert-mysqli-result-to-json

Comment: `while($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
            $myArray[] = $row;
    }
    echo json_encode($myArray);`

Comment: dentro do while, tipo isso? $myArray[$i]="conteudo e variáveis"; $i++; 
fora do while json_encode($myArray);

Comment: Isso, tem que montar um array com todo o conteúdo que você quer converter em json e no final dar um `echo json_encode($myArray);`

Comment: Acessando direto seu script php ele exibe algo?

Comment: Funciona acessando direto, porém leva o navegador para a página php. Já achei a resposta em outro lugar. Valeu!

Answer (score -1):

fetchLojas.php ficou assim:

```
<?php

require_once "dbconf.php";
$dbconf = new db_connection;

$dbconf->connect_db(); //estabelecendo conexão com o banco de dados
$conn = $dbconf->conn;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM lojas ORDER BY id_lojas DESC";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
// output data of each row
  while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

    $myArray[$i]='
    <div class="panel panel-primary">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h1 class="panel-title"><b>Loja '. $row["nome"].'</b>
        &nbsp&nbsp<a href="http://digyx.com.br/bkp/lojas/editar-lojas.php?loja='.$row['id_lojas'].'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Editar"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        <span class="sr-only">Editar Loja</span>
        &nbsp&nbsp<a href="http://digyx.com.br/bkp/lojas/exclui-lojas.php?loja='.$row['id_lojas'].'" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Exluir"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></a>
        <span class="sr-only">Excluir Loja</span>
        </h1>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Nome Banco: </b>'. $row["nomebanco"].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Nome arquivo .sql: </b>'. $row["nomearquivo_sql"].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Nome arquivo .tar.gz: </b>'. $row["nomearquivo_targz"].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Usuário do banco de dados: </b>'. $row["bduser"].'</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">
        <h4><b>Diretorio da loja: </b>'. $row["pasta_loja"].'</h4>
      </div>
    </div>

    <hr>
    ';

    $i++;
}
} else {
  $myArray = "Nenhuma loja cadastrada!";
}

echo json_encode($myArray);

$dbconf->close_db(); //fechando conexão com banco de dados
```

ainda não funciona

Comment: [edite](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/197293/edit) sua pergunta acrescentando mais informações a mesma, e não criando uma resposta pra pergunta